# How can i combine NDVI3g bi-monthly into monthly composite using maximum value method in R

Tags: r

I am working with NDVI3g data sets. My problem is that i am trying to create monthly composite data sets from the bi-monthly original data sets using maximum value composite method in R. Please i need your help, because i tried my possible best, but couldn't figure it out. The problem with data is that the first composite in a month is named as for example below;

```
AF99sep15a.n14-VI3g: first 15 days
AF99sep15b.n14-VI3g : Last 15 days;
```

I have 31 years data sets (i.e 1982-2012).

Kindly need your help on how to combine the whole data sets into a monthly composite.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking. Do you need help generating the filenames? Do you need help merging the data?

Comment: Which package do you use ? `raster`, 'spacetime', etc ? are your raster data stacked ? If you want some help you have to give more information and provide a sample code. Not really related but is the NDVI3g publicly available ?

Comment: CrazyCasta. I mean merging the data together from bi-monthly to a single monthly files.

Comment: I loaded my data sets as layer brick using raster package.          fun <- function(x) {  
gimms.ts = ts(x, start=c(1982), end=c(2012,24), frequency=24)
z=zoo(gimms.ts)
x <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon(index(z)), "average") }

gimms.monthly <- calc(gimms,fun); where gimms is my NDVI brick

Answer (score 1):

given RasterStack gimms and that you want to average sequential pairs, I think you can do

```
i <- rep(1:(nlayers(gimms)/2), each =2)
x <- stackApply(gimms, i, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also check out the **gimms** package which includes the function `monthlyComposite` (including optional parallel support) to create monthly maximum value composites from the initial half-monthly layers. Needless to say, the function is heavily based on `stackApply` from the **raster** package.